I can't display map tiles other than MAPNIK with osmdroid, I want a simplier map
I'm new here, I'm working on a small gps game that display a simple map.
I'm using Kotlin with osmdroid 6.1.18
I successfully displayed a map with MAPNIK as tile source :
MapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK)
MAPNIK map
However, this map display too much information for people to play with.
I want to display a map with only roads and paths (maybe their names, but that's all !).
So I tried to display other tile sourced maps : HIKEBIKEMAP, OPEN_SEAMAP, PUBLIC_TRANSPORT, etc ...
But all of them are blank :
Blank map
I searched in the small FAQ from the GitHub and tried every solutions related to my problem :

setting the "user agent"
creating a "network_security_config.xml"
checking permissions in "AndroidManifest.xml"

But it didn't change a thing.
So I tried to use the Debug mode from Configuration.getInstance().isDebugMode = true but I'm drowning from the amount of information I get in the Logcat. I don't know what error is related to my map problem.
I stopped searching with the debug mode and focused on setting the TileSource through URLs like this. But the map still blank, even if I tried different URLs recommended in other stackoverflow's solutions.

I doubt the URLs links are broken.

They are actually :
Downloading Maptile from url: https://tiles.wmflabs.org/hikebike/18/132453/91237.png
SqlCache - Tile doesn't exist: HikeBikeMap/13/4139/2851
SqlCache - Tile doesn't exist: HikeBikeMap/12/2069/1425
Archives - Tile doesn't exist: /12/2069/1425
Downloading Maptile from url: https://tiles.wmflabs.org/hikebike/18/132456/91233.png
Archives - Tile doesn't exist: /13/4139/2851
SqlCache - Tile doesn't exist: HikeBikeMap/12/2069/1425
Archives - Tile doesn't exist: /12/2069/1425


I'm out of options and kinda lost, so I'm asking help for just displaying a simplier map !

I'm searching up-to-date links for tiles for now.
Here's my MainActivity :
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 1
    private lateinit var map : MapView
    private lateinit var text : TextView
    private lateinit var mapController : IMapController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Configuration.getInstance().apply {
            userAgentValue = applicationContext.packageName
            load( applicationContext, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext))
            // isDebugMode = true  // DEBUG
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // DEBUG TextView
        //text = findViewById(R.id.debugText)
        //Configuration.getInstance().apply {
        //    text.append("cacheMapTileCount : $cacheMapTileCount\n" +
        //                "cacheMapTileOvershoot : $cacheMapTileOvershoot\n")
        //}

        // TILES
        val tileSource: ITileSource = XYTileSource(
            "HOT", 1, 20, 256, ".png", arrayOf(
                "http://a.tile.openstreetmap.fr/",
                "http://b.tile.openstreetmap.fr/",
                "http://c.tile.openstreetmap.fr/"
            ), "© OpenStreetMap contributors"
        )

        // Map creation from Tiles
        map = findViewById(R.id.map)
        map.apply {
            setTileSource(tileSource)
            setBuiltInZoomControls(true)
            overlayManager
        }

        // Start from this point
        val startPoint = GeoPoint(47.9, 1.9)
        mapController = map.controller
        mapController.setZoom(18.0)
        mapController.setCenter(startPoint)

        // Display my location
        // val mLocationOverlay = MyLocationNewOverlay(GpsMyLocationProvider(applicationContext), map)
        // mLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation()
        // map.overlays.add(mLocationOverlay)

        // Display a compass
        // val compassOverlay = CompassOverlay(applicationContext, InternalCompassOrientationProvider(applicationContext), map)
        // compassOverlay.enableCompass()
        // map.overlays.add(compassOverlay)

        // Display lonlat grid
        //val overlay = LatLonGridlineOverlay2()
        //map.overlays.add(overlay)

        // Add map rotation
        // val rotationGestureOverlay = RotationGestureOverlay(map)
        // rotationGestureOverlay.isEnabled
        // map.setMultiTouchControls(true)
        // map.overlays.add(rotationGestureOverlay)

        // Interest point creation
        // var items = mutableListOf<OverlayItem>()
        // var origin = OverlayItem("Statue de Jeanne d'Arc","Héroïne d'Orléans", GeoPoint(47.8,2.0))
        //var draw : Drawable = origin.getMarker(0)
        // items.add(origin)
        // items.add(OverlayItem("3030","Random", GeoPoint(0.1,0.1)))

        // Map listener
        // val listener = object : OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem> {
        //     override fun onItemSingleTapUp(index : Int, item : OverlayItem): Boolean {
        //         println("MAP : onItemSingleTapUp")  // DEBUG
        //         return true
        //     }

        //     override fun onItemLongPress(index : Int, item : OverlayItem): Boolean {
        //         println("MAP : onItemLongPress")    // DEBUG
        //         return false
        //     }
        // }
        // var mOverlay = ItemizedOverlayWithFocus(applicationContext, items, listener)
        // mOverlay.setFocusItemsOnTap(true)
        // map.overlays.add(mOverlay)

        // Inside your activity
        /*if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission is not granted, request it
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION
            )
        }*/

    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        map.onPause()
        println("MAP : onPause")  // DEBUG
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        map.onResume()
        println("MAP : onResume") // DEBUG
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        val permissionsToRequest = ArrayList<String>()
        var i = 0
        while (i < grantResults.size) {
            permissionsToRequest.add(permissions[i])
            i++
        }
        if (permissionsToRequest.size > 0) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                permissionsToRequest.toTypedArray(),
                REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE)
        }
    }

}

My permissions from "AndroidManifest" :
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />

Thanks all in advance for reading and answering, if you need more information do not hesitate.

Check the log for errors regarding downloading these tiles. You should be able to identify the relevant log messages by searching for URLs.

Are you willing to pay for map tiles? There may be free options too, but they are limited in amount of monthly tile downloads or some similar metric. You'll want "bitmap tiles" and there are several optional sources like e.g. geofabrik.de, geoapify.com, maptilesapi.com, stadiamaps.com, thunderforest.com and maptiler.com. Some have free options for evaluation or for a small scale hobby project.

Many tile sources may require an API key that needs to be included either in the URL or in the HTTP request headers.

I learned how to use logs and I found out that URLs are indeed broken.
I need to find new tiles' URLs or create my own tiles.  For paying Tiles, I don't know, it would be funny my little game being used worldwide, but heh, I'm not at this state now ... I don't see the point for now, but maybe in the future if prices are reasonable.

You can take a look at e.g. https://stadiamaps.com/pricing/ and https://www.thunderforest.com/pricing/ as small-scale non-commercial use for fun is free.
